# Joomla how to regenerate the session ID to prevent session fixation

Tags: php, session, joomla, joomla1.5

Joomla 1.5.15

I need to renew the session ID when a user logs in to prevent session fixation that is possible in 1.5.15. I realise I can update to latest version and would be fixed but for various reasons I can't update right now.

I have an authentication plugin which handles the logins (I don't use the #__users table), in my plugin I authenticate a user/pass with a web service. I would like to be able to regenerate th session ID at this point in the plugin.

I have tried simply session_regenerate_id() which does renew it but I lose all session data and can't login. I know Joomla uses its own session classes but I don't know if there is a function to do this.

Thanks

Comment: I would HIGHLY recommend updating to 1.5.22. All of the releases since 1.5.15 have been security releases, your site is vulnerable.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`JSession::fork()`](http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Framework/Session/JSession.html#fork).

```
$session =& JFactory::getSession();
$session->fork();
```

All it really does is `session_regenerate_id()` in the background, but it makes sure the session is active first before it does so.  You shouldn't lose any data by doing this (and if you do, there may be a bug somewhere)...

For Joomla 2.5 and Joomla 3.5 session fixation you can refer to the solution suggested for [session fixation in Joomla 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26095399/session-fixation-in-joomla-2-5)

Comment: Tried that and it does renew the ID but can't login, session data seems to be lost. In the plugin if good user/pass I set the response status to JAUTHENTICATE_STATUS_SUCCESS then I call fork() then I return true to indicate a successful login.

Comment: @user5953: And it does log you in of you don't regenerate the session_id?